# Apache cannot pickup new index page - Ruby on Rails - EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, amazon-ec2, passenger

I created a new project on my RoR server and I want to redirect apache to pick up the new index file from my app/views/home/index.html.erb but it does not seem to work.

This is my virtual server conf file before i created the new index file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blog/public
    ErrorLog logs/example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/example.com-access_log common
<Directory /var/www/html/blog/public>
        Allow from all
    PassengerEnabled off 
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And after i deleted the public/index.html

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blog/app/views/home/
    ErrorLog logs/example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/example.com-access_log common
<Directory /var/www/html/blog/app/views/home/>
        Allow from all
    PassengerEnabled off 
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I had to specify RailsEnv in  httpd.conf and then touch tmp/restart.txt

Answer (score 1):

## Completely EDITed last answer

Please post your routes file, but change back your DocumentRoot line to

`DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blog/public`

You point to your public directory, and your routes will tell the app to show app/home/index, not apache (if you are using rails as it should be used).

in config/routes.rb make sure you have the line `root :to => 'home#index'`

### update 1

Check if the line that says Options has the right arguments and you need it more importantly. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options Personally I use nginx and unicorn, but I don't remember that line when i did mess around with Passenger.

Comment: I had the correct output before I did this, then it just gives me the apache page. I did the touch command as well and still nothing

Comment: I do have root :to => 'home#index' my apache is restored to DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blog/public i did an apache restart and touch restart.txt inside the tmp folder of my application and still is not picking it up

Comment: let's backtrack, in development on your local machine, you can access it by going to localhost:3000 after you do `rails server` right? please confirm.

Comment: Oh and change this line too <Directory /var/www/html/blog/app/public>

Comment: I am on Amazon-ec2 server, I don't work on local. I did change the directory and document root, I also tried to kill passenger because of some reported bugs with touch restart.txt. So i don't know what else to do

Comment: You don't work on localhost? odd enough. How do you know rails works at all then and it's apache?

Comment: check the apache logs as it doesn't look like the rails server is getting hit.

Comment: it gives me this error: Directory index Forbitten by Options directive /var/www/html/blog/public